# Numpy casting a shape nm with a shape pnq to get a shape pnmq?

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to cast a m x n matrix with a p x n x q matrix in a particular way. In effect, I want to replace each element of the p x n x q array with the m x n array added to the element it replaced.
Formally, given mn matrix X and pnq matrix Y, I want to fill a qnmp (not pmnq) numpy such that,

[This relation is True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a3IE.png)

How would I go about doing this in numpy without creating a separate array and filling it out with the above relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, align the axes for broadcasting, and then use transposing to move the axes into the desired output shape.

```
import numpy as np

M, N, P, Q = 2, 3, 4, 5
X = np.arange(M * N).reshape(M, N)
Y = np.arange(P * N * Q).reshape(P, N, Q)

# X: (1, M, N, 1)
# Y: (P, 1, N, Q)
# =============== Broadcast
# Z: (P, M, N, Q)
Z = X[None, :, :, None] + Y[:, None, :, :]

# Transpose the output array to achieve
# Z: (Q, N, M, P)
Z = Z.T

# Or alternatively do the transposing of X and Y first, then align axes.
```

Comment: Too bad there isn't an `einsum` equivalent for the sum of sum, `np.einsum('mn,pnq->qnmp', X, Y)`  is quite short ;)

Comment: Man you are fast...

Comment: Actually, I'm just thinking you could use `einsum` with `Z = np.einsum('mn,pnq->qnmp', np.ones_like(X), Y) + np.einsum('mn,pnq->qnmp', X, np.ones_like(Y))` :p

Comment: Love the einsum magic!! Would indeed be cool if you could specify the "operator" and the "reducer"!

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs it's fun but likely much less efficient than broadcasting, but yes being able to change the operator would be nice ;)

Comment: @mozway Who knows? Sometimes broadcasting then reducing ends up needing a more dimensional array to store the intermediate result... I'd say there is some potential :)

Comment: Years ago there was a `issue` requesting a generalization of `einsum` to allow other `product` and `sum` combinations.  But that was before it was refined to make better use of the BLAS library (i.e. like `matmul`).  The earlier array language `APL` had such a generalization,  I think matrix product used `A+.xB` syntax. `.` forms a dyadic composite function )